# compare elements from list in a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I am trying to compare list elements with a json file and if there is a match then return certain values and create a json response.
here are my json data

```
[
 {
    "evi": 1223,
    "evn": "testapp1",
    "conf": {
        "c_gr": "tot",
        "c_id": "112"
    }
 },
 {
    "evi": 6759,
    "evn": "testapp2",
    "conf": {
        "c_gr": "tot",
        "c_id": "112"
    }
 },
  {
    "evi": 3352,
    "evn": "testapp3",
    "conf": {
        "c_gr": "tot7",
        "c_id": "112"
    }
 }
]
```

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
response=requests.post('https://testaapp.com', headers=headers, data=data)
resp_json=response.json()
if response.status_code == 200:
    print ('working fine...!!')
else:
    print ('notworking !!')
metadata=resp_json['data']
m_list=[1123, 123445, 61887, 3352, 35811488976]
final_lst_data1 = []
final_lst_data2 = []
for key in m_list:
    temp1= key
    for keya in metadata:
        if temp1 in metadata[keya]['evi']:
           final_lst_data1.append(metadata['evn']) #return the names
           final_lst_data2.append(metadata['evn'], metadata['conf']) #return evn and conf values after checking and then dump it to json from list in same json format if not possible then convert to json from list, not sure how to do this here.
```

But this doesnt works as it gives me below error

```
    if key in metadata[keya]['evi']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: @Nathan tried `for keya in range(len(metadata))` got this error `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Comment: @Nathan please check here for actual son data https://jsfiddle.net/sa9tLygk/

Answer (score 1):

You are using a dictionary as an index. When you say "for keya in metadata:", keya is a dictionary that refers to the list of dictionaries inside 'metadata'. So, you don't need to use metadata[keya] to access each element, you can just use 'keya'.

```
for keya in metadata:
    if temp1 == keya['evi']:
       final_lst_data1.append(keya['evn'])
       final_lst_data2.append([keya['evn'], keya['conf']])
```

Comment: tried the same it gives me error `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` under `final_lst_data2.append(keya['evn'], keya['conf'])`

Comment: Also as I had asked in the question that if I need to convert the list response of `final_lst_data2` in json how do I do that ?

Comment: The error you are getting is because of the last line, you can simply enclose the two arguments inside a list.

Comment: As for the json, json.dumps should work fine. That is why I didn't include it in the answer.

Comment: I have down the same declared list like this `final_lst_data2 = []` and appended like this `final_lst_data2.append(keya['evn'], keya['conf'])` But still I get the same error can you provide it in answer?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be expecting spoonfeeding on this platform. Use final_lst_data2.append([keya['evn']mkeya['conf']]).....  I have made the edit on the answer too.

Comment: Also my expected output for  `final_json = json.dumps(final_lst_data2)` should be the one I mentioned in the question, will it be same if I do `json.dumps()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205426/discussion-between-thomas-and-shivam-kaushik).